# Issue in base64 encoding and decoding of high resolution image in Android

Tags: android, encoding, base64, decoding

I am using Base64 for converting image to string and i do this using below code

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.facebook);  
         ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100 , stream);
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

by using name value pair i will send this image to server and in another activity i need to fetch this image and i use following code to decode the image

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageStr, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);


                System.out.println("bitmap "+decodedByte);
                imageViewProfile.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

wheni print this decodedByte it will give null..

and if the image is of small resolution it will work perfectly,, thanks for any help

Comment: Try changing Base64.NO_WRAP to Base64.DEFAULT

Comment: ya i tried it but no changes it will give null. actually i want to upload photo to server its of high resolution.

Comment: Do you fail in uploading the image too?

Comment: you should not be encoding large images with base64 with this method. you'll have memory issues. You should either not encode your image or use a stream encoder.

Comment: @carnal image uploaded successfully but getting the image iam using json parsing and the string am getting is half the string present in server